# Read text file into vector (double, double, string)? C++

Tags: c++, file, text, vector, double

I have a text format that uses *latitude*, *longitude* and *name of location*
, for example:

```
41.3333 34.3232 Old Building
```

I have to read this text file (from the command line), split each line by white space, use `stod` to convert the `lat` and `long` back into a `double`, then read the whole file into a vector or a list.

This is what I currently I am  stuck on:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Distance{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    string location;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // If the user didn't provide a filename command line argument,
    // print an error and exit.
    if (argc <= 1){
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <Filename>" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    char *pFilename = argv[1];

    string buf; // Have a buffer string
    stringstream ss(argv[1]); // Insert the string into a stream
    vector<string> tokens; // Create vector to hold our words

    while (ss >> buf)
        tokens.push_back(buf);
}
```

### Question:

1. Could I have some insight on how to proceed with the implementation?

Answer: from here I need to look at each line in the file and split them by whitespace then store the file in a vector by what they are. So the first number of the text file would be latitude, second longitude, and third (string) is location.

Comment: You could start by considering `fstream` for input and its respective syntax.

Comment: `stringstream ss(argv[1]);` only puts the filename and not the contents of the file into `ss`.

Comment: You *could* overload `::operator>>` for `Distance`.

Answer (score 1):

These are some general points whenever you end up using C++ :-

1. Avoid pointers if you can. Prefer references or composite classes like string in place of char *.
2. The C++ reference online can help you find out the correct usage very easily.
3. GDB can help you in most of the cases for such problems as in your question.

As suggested in the comments , you have to read the file in the string stream first and then only you can parse it. I have not compiled the code below but I hope it gives you a good idea about how to do this.In this case, the file is standard input. You can read from that in the following manner :-

```
char buffer[1000]; // assumine each line of input will not be more than this
while(cin.getline(buffer , 1000)) // constant 1000 can be moved to a MACRO
{
    // cin does not eat up the newline character. So we have to do something like this to make it work
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
    //discard characters until newline is found
    stringstream ss(buffer); // Insert the string into a stream
    vector<string> tokens; // Create vector to hold our words
    string buf ;

    Distance distance ; 
    ss>>buf;
    distance.x = stod(buf);
    tokens.push_back(buf);

    ss>>buf;
    distance.x = stod(buf);
    tokens.push_back(buf);

    ss>>buf;
    distance.x = buf;
    tokens.push_back(buf);
}
```